# UK Visitor Visa Refusal

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I applied for standard visitor Visa with a sponsor from my fiance, but my Visa was refused with this reason below:

You have applied for leave to enter to visit the UK for 21 days for tourism.

You state that your partner is paying for all the costs in relation to your visit and I am satisfied that he is willing and able to do so. However, I must also assess your personal circumstances.

You state that you are employed as a contact center team leader with PT VADS Indonesia earning 5000000.00 IDR (£256.68 [www.oanda.com](http://www.oanda.com)) per month. In support of your application, you have submitted your bank statement. I note that there are deposits in this account that correlate with your stated monthly income however I also note that there are other deposits that are unrelated to the amount you state you earn. For example, there is a deposit of 4,750,000IDR (£243.84) made on the 11 May and then another deposit of 6,185.766IDR (£317.55) made on the 20 May. The documents you have provided do not demonstrate the origin of these funds and therefore I am not satisfied that the funds in your account are genuinely available to you for your exclusive use or that they accurately reflect your financial position.
I am not satisfied as to your intentions for visiting the UK, that you are a genuine visitor or that you will leave at the end of the period specified by you. I, therefore, refuse your application under paragraph 4.2 (a) and (c) of Appendix V of the United Kingdom Immigration Rules.[image]

I wanna reapply but I have a doubt to put my bank statement again and history of my bank account, besides that I actually work in shifting schedule, so every month I Will receive a different number of my salary, how I explain them?
If I reapply what exact salary I have to put there? Can I put the basic salary only?

Comment: Where did the extra deposits (eg in May) they refer to come from? Were they related to your employment? Did you submit payslips? The problem isn’t your job income, it’s other, unexplained deposits.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e)

Comment: Ini did not explain for more detail of my deposit and i did not put my Payslip as well, means i just need to explain n put more evidance in my new application right?

Comment: @Wanti Wikaksono Indonesia is not on the travel corridor list https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/self-isolating-when-you-arrive A trip of 21 days would mean you spending 14 days in self-isolation. Even if you can fix the problem with your financial documentation, your proposed trip isn’t very credible right now. Depending on when you intend to travel, and with one refusal already, you may well do better to wait a couple of months at least before re-applying.

Comment: I don't mind to have quarantine for 14 days, For new application I put 1 month to travel, n I Will reapply for the end of December 2020. I reapply for December for I am worried if it is gonna be harder on 1 Jan 2021